# Is there a solution to the absolute value of an expression which results in a negative value?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

The equation given: $ \mid x - 4 \mid = -3$.

My instinct ([and example 2 in this article](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/SolveAbsValueEqns.aspx)) tells me that there shouldn't be any solution as there would be no value of x which would result in a negative result.

However, [the solution given here](http://www.slader.com/textbook/9780840068132-algebra-and-trigonometry-3rd-edition/116/exercises/12/) does give a value of $x$.

My question: which one (or two) of us is correct?

Comment: Your instinct is correct. The absolute value is, by definition, $\ge 0$

Comment: $|x-4|=-3$ has no solution.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Could you also write that as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: It seems that the question in the link should be $|x-4| = 3$, since then you have $(x-4) = + 3$ (giving $x=7$) or $(x-4) = -3$ (giving $x=1$) so it is probably a typo. You may wish to inform the web site.

Comment: @jim No, actually, even in the book whose solution is given in the site has the exact same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

community wiki answer so the question can be closed

You are correct.  The equation $|x - 4| = -3$ does not have a solution since the absolute value of a number cannot be negative.